# Pycharm 2021.3 problem with pasting multiline input

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I have a beginner problem with pycharm console and pasting multiline input. I use this code:

```
def multi_input():
    try:
        while True:
            data=input()
            if not data: break
            yield data
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        return

ips = list(multi_input())
print(len(ips))   # test
```

This code works fine in Windows CMD, when I paste 300 lines I have a list with 300 items.

When I do the same in Pycharm Console I get a list with 1 item. Single lines are concatenated with \n. Can anyone explain this difference? How to fix this issue?

Input:

```
10.63.134.223
10.130.140.230
10.72.206.50
10.130.210.185
10.63.136.165
```

Output when using Pycharm console:

```
ips
['10.63.134.223\n10.130.140.230\n10.72.206.50\n10.130.210.185\n10.63.136.165']
```

Output when using Windws CMD:

```
['10.63.134.223', '10.130.140.230', '10.72.206.50', '10.130.210.185', '10.63.136.165']
```

Comment: Hope it's clearer now what the problem is :)

Comment: Copy pasting the same input you put here as-is gives the expected output...

Comment: @lukfat what version of pycharm? this code works good in the ide terminal and python console